# What does the proportion 1:3 mean in the following example?

Tags: meaning, mathematics

What does the proportion 1:3 mean in the following example?

> In this case the holes were filled with a mixture of cement and sand in the ratio 1:3.

Comment: You, yourself, have described the term "1:3" as both a "proportion" and a "ratio". So what else do you want to know?

Comment: It's just that in French we don't use this kind of writing to express ratios, so I wanted to be sure of what it represents

Comment: How would you express this in French?

Comment: Actually, after searching, I found that it is also used in French, but in rather technical contexts. We also often say, literally translated into English, "1 for 3", sometimes 1/3 but in this case it should not be mistaken with the other meaning of 1/3 = one third

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that the holes were filled with a mixture that was 1/4th cement and 3/4ths sand.

Comment: ok I understand

Comment: no, it would be 1:3, but this answer is confusing because it doesn't discuss ratios, like the question asked. 1:3 here means "1 part cement for every 3 parts sand". That's 4 parts total, so the mixture would indeed be 1/4 cement and 3/4 sand.

Answer (score 1):

It is a representation of a dimensionless mathematical relationship between the amounts of the two ingredients in the formula. For each single unit of cement, you are to use three units of sand.